# how can i customoize 'ui-slider-handle' background images?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have two range sliders in my page, and I would like to implement different control images for each slider. I changed `ui-slider-handle` but this affected both sliders. Is there a way to change this for each slider individually? Or some other way of having this functionality?

[My code so far...]http://jsfiddle.net/hari034/EQ2zx/3/)

Comment: That jsfiddle doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: hi pointy ..that is sample code..it will not run.

Comment: you do know when you enable to jQueryUI slider you can specify a class you need to specify different classes for each then use them as the child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsfiddel is quite confusing, mabe I got it right: change your css rules in

```
#time .ui-slider
{
    ...
}

#fare .ui-slider
{
    ...
}
```

If this is not the answer, please be more specific or update your fiddle.